# Can I create a single user with public ssh key in AWS SFTP which can be accessible from any machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sftp

I have created a SFTP server in AWS and added a user with ssh public key,

I need to access the SFTP server from the same user from different machine.

How can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two requirements:

- the machines need to have network access to your server. For PUBLIC servers this just means internet access. For VPC servers, you would need to be in the VPC or attach an elastic IP and then you just need internet like PUBLIC.
- You would need to replicate the SSH private key to all machines that you want to connect from.

As long as the machine has access to the server and user’s private key you can login using the servers endpoint/ip by following the steps outlined here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/getting-started.html#getting-started-transfer-file